# Re-opening module defined in a gem from lib directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a file that looks like this

```
module Devise
  module Mailers
    module Helpers

      def initialize_from_record(record)
        record = hack_record(record)
        @scope_name = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(record)
        @resource = instance_variable_set("@#{devise_mapping.name}", record)
      end

      protected

      # monkey patch :D
      def hack_record(record)
        record.kind_of?(Hash) ? kmodel(record).where(:email=>record.first[1]['email']).first : record
      end

      def kmodel(record)
        record.first[0].camelize.constantize
      end

    end
  end
end
```

It obviously re-opens a Devise module. If I put it in initializers all is great. However, if I put it in lib/devise/mailers it does get read however it can't find the other methods from the module that are defined in the Devise gem. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

This is because it's loading *your* Devise module before Devise's. They're named the same and placed at identical (at least, according to the load path) paths.

If you want to define new methods on this module then how about defining a different module entirely and including that into Devise's?

**lib/devise/mailers/helpers_extensions.rb**

```
module Devise
  module Mailers
    module HelpersExtensions
      # your code
    end
  end
end

Devise::Mailers::Helpers.send :include, Devise::Mailers::HelpersExtensions
```

Comment: Actually that still has the same issue -- the other methods aren't found.